# Irreducible polynomials of degree $d$ such that $[x]$ generates $\mathbf{F}_{p^d}^{\times}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

It is often convenient to represent the field $\mathbf{F}_{p^d}$ as $\mathbf{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$, where $f$ is irreducible with degree $d$, $f$ has just a few nonzero terms, and $[x]$ itself is the generator of the multiplicative group $\mathbf{F}_{p^d}^{\times}$. How can we show that such polynomials for which $[x]$ is a cyclic generator and such that the polynomial is sparse exist, and how can we efficiently find them?

Comment: If you're talking about proofs, you will need to define "just a few."

Comment: @anon What I mean is as few as possible, for example, suppose $f,g\in\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ are irreducibles, and $\operatorname{deg}(f)=\operatorname{deg}(g)=100$. If $f$ has say $3$ nonzero terms, but $g$ has say $50$, then it is nicer to work with $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(f(x))$ rather than in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(g(x))$, even though $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(f(x))\cong \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(g(x))\cong\mathbb{F}_{2^{100}}$. I suppose this is slightly sketchy though...

Comment: Saying sparse in the context of proofs is superfluous; as long as one such $f$ exists, then surely such an $f$ with minimal number of nonzero coefficients *exists*. So technically you want to (a) show irreducible $f$ exist of degree $d$ such that $({\Bbb F}_p[x]/(f))^\times=\langle x\rangle$ and (b) know how to find the sparsest such $f$ efficiently.

Comment: @anon Thanks, that's a much nicer/more concise way to state it.

Comment: I don't know of an efficient method of finding one of the sparsest (or proving that a given primitive polynomial has the lowest possible number of terms). I use [tables like this](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/papers/CS-07-593/primitive-polynomial-table.txt). I believe that this is difficult in general. The somewhat analogous problem of finding the smallest primitive root modulo a prime number is also hard. IIRC there are results of the form: "assuming generalized Riemann hypothesis there exists a primitive root of size at most..." Something like this may be known here, too, but IDK.